# Allocation Failed error in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a script which is trying to read 100,000 files(.txt around 800KB Each). I use `fs.readFileSync()` to read each file, push the contents into a small DB, and then proceed to read the next file. I only store half of the files in DB however. The script is fast in the beginning but slows down when it reaches 38000 files and eventually dies with the below error.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I tried running with more memory, expose GC but to no avail.

Anyone has any guesses ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the files.
Use [fs.close(fd, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) function after finishing operations on it.

Since you are using sync version, then [fs.closeSync(fd)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_closesync_fd) will likely appeal you more.